# Fourier sampling in positive characteristic

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, fourier-sampling

Fourier sampling is used in the hidden subgroup problem in Shor's algorithm for $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ in the abelian case and the symmetric group $S_n$ for [attempts at graph isomorphism](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/050644896) in the nonabelian case.

Representations are over $\mathbb{C}$ in both cases. Is there a generalization to $\text{char}(k)=p > 0$?

There are some [gaps in knowledge](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458191/what-is-dim-d-lambda-for-the-symmetric-group) for the modular representations of $S_n$. The [modular Fourier transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364644/fourier-transform-on-finite-groups-in-characteristic-p0) isn't quite developed. However, for [finite abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_over_a_ring) it's straightforward as long as $p \nmid n$.